# TypeError: this.state.persons.map is not a function while using axios.get in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I am beginner in React, trying to fetch data from https://api.randomuser.me. I am using state persons to store the json data and displaying it in the div -> data-wrapper
For now I just want to extract the name from the json file and made sure that the state persons is an empty array and not a string
Please help

reactjs file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './form.css'
import axios from 'axios'


class form extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            answer:'',
            persons:[]
        }
        this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('https://api.randomuser.me')
            .then(res=>{
                console.log(res);
                this.setState({persons:res.data});
            })
    }

    handleSubmit=(e)=>{
      
    }

    handleChange=(e)=>{
        this.setState({
            answer:e.target.value,
        })
    }
    render(){
 
        return (
            <div>
                <section className="login">
                    <div className="loginContainer">
                        <div className="heading">
                            
                        </div>
                        <div className="data-wrapper">
                          {this.state.persons.map(person=><h2>{person.name}</h2>)}
                            
                        </div>
                
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default form
```

json

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "gender": "female",
      "name": {
        "title": "Miss",
        "first": "Zuzanna",
        "last": "Wessel"
      },
      "location": {
        "street": {
          "number": 4174,
          "name": "Bård Skolemesters vei"
        },
        "city": "Haugo",
        "state": "Oppland",
        "country": "Norway",
        "postcode": "2832",
        "coordinates": {
          "latitude": "48.2641",
          "longitude": "49.1001"
        },
        "timezone": {
          "offset": "+5:00",
          "description": "Ekaterinburg, Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    "seed": "bdb282c01c741bda",
    "results": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "version": "1.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the data from the correct `key`. You need to set this:

```
this.setState({ persons: res.data.results });
```

Also, you need to render the name as a string, currently, you are rendering object which will throw an error.

```
 <h2>{person.name.first}</h2>
```